# Is it safe to store custom lists outside /lists?

Tags: content-and-structure

In a complex custom application based on SharePoint, I have a bunch of lists and libraries.

I would like to store them under a dedicated folder :

```
~site/MySolution/List1
~site/MySolution/List2
~site/MySolution/Library1
...
```

Instead of the traditional pattern:

```
~site/Lists/List1
~site/Lists/List2
~site/Library1
...
```

Is there any restriction in such structure?

Answer (score 1):

Lists actually do live under a folder called “Lists” in each site, so they’re easy to identify.  A list called “Test” will have a URL of `http://somename/lists/test`

I don't see any restriction, rather it is for easy management of it. You can change the URL or you can create the List outside the /List" .

https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/change-the-url-of-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/